# Java genegic class that takes generic type parameter

Tags: java, generics

E.g. I have:

```
interface Consumer<F extends FoodType>
interface Vegetarian extends Consumer<Grass>
interface Predator extends Consumer<Meat>
```

I want to have something like:

```
class Feeder<C extends Consumer<F>>
```

to use `F` type parameter within `Feeder` class declaration. The aim is to pass only informative type parameter and to take up other type parameters from the passed ones:

```
new Feeder<Vegetarian>().buyFood(bluegrassIsGrassAndCouldNotBeMeat)
```

Comment: What do you mean for `informative type`?

Comment: It means that other passed types doesn't carry information about this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is going to use two generic types it's going to need two generic parameters even if they are dependent.

```
class Feeder<C extends Consumer<F>, F extends FoodType>{}
```

If may be useful to be a bit more flexible.

```
class Feeder<C extends Consumer<? super F>, F extends FoodType>{}
```

(Josh Bloch's uses the acronym PECS: Producer's `extend`; Consumer's `super`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
  class Feeder<C extends Consumer<? extends FoodType>>
```

or simply:

```
  class Feeder<C extends Consumer<?>>
```

but there is a difference between them. As far as I understood from your question (it's not very clear) you want one of these two.

Comment: yes, I agree.I was editing ... it's not very clear from the question what he's up to

Comment: I'm with @Ben. I think you're going to come a cropper when it comes to calling the `feed` method.